# Moment.js .toDate() returns one year later than expected result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a date. `2019-12-13 13:40:00` which stands for December 13th 2019 at 1:40 pm. When I parse this with moment.js...

```js
moment(props.data[index].date, 'gggg-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

the `_d` shows that the date is `Sun Dec 13 2020 14:30:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`.
I have seen many explanations on the moment GitHub where people have this issue but its related to time zones, however an entire year difference is not a time zone problem.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gggg` in the second argument is for parsing in [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) format.
Try doing `moment(props.data[index].date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`